# WordPress - Advanced Custom Fields - Pull Data From Another Template Inside Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

Having a bit of a problem, i'm using ACF for WordPress, i have defined the color picker on the services template which color codes the page heading in a color you select. This template then has a page link which relates to another template: case studies - the case studies template has a select option where you select the page from services that relates to the case study. I can get those values out as it is on the case studies template. How do i go about getting the color picker value from the services page and apply the color to the case studies page? Here is what i have done so far;

```
<div class="caseStudies">
    <h1 class="pageTitle uppercase"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div class="caseStudyIntro"><?php echo the_content(); ?></div>

    <?php
    foreach($caseStudyChildren as $caseStudies)
    {       
        $cStudyId           = $caseStudies->ID;                                         
        $cStudyThumbnail    = get_field("thumbnail_image", $cStudyId);
        $cStudyRelation     = get_field("case_study_relation", $cStudyId);
        $cStudyContent      = get_field("case_study_content", $cStudyId);
    ?>

    <div class="caseStudyItem">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPaddingLeft">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cStudyId); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $cStudyThumbnail['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cStudyThumbnail['alt']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail cStudyThumb" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="title uppercase">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cStudyId); ?>" class="dark-black">
                        <?php echo get_the_title($cStudyId); ?> <?php echo '- '.$cStudyRelation; ?>
                    </a>
                </h1>
                <div class="study">
                    <?php echo wp_trim_words($cStudyContent, 40, '...'); ?> 
                </div>                  
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cStudyId); ?>" class="readMore red uppercase">Read More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <?php
    }/* foreach end */?>

</div>
```

This line here is where i am adding the services link that relates to the case study (so it almost acts like a tag)

```
<?php echo get_the_title($cStudyId); ?> <?php echo '- '.$cStudyRelation; ?>
```

Backend Configuration

[image: servicesTemplate]

[image: CASESTUDYtEMPLATE]
[image: frontendPage]

Hope that made some sense, if not let me know and i can add to it more. PHP newbie here so go easy one me, haha!

Thanks.

Comment: Is `$cStudyRelation` a post ID? Title? What is it?

Comment: @mevius apologies, it is a "select" field type that is defined using ACF.

Comment: But what does it return?

Comment: @mevius it returns the service page(s) that I've defined to appear in the dropdown http://prntscr.com/8hwgci & http://prntscr.com/8hwgq2

Comment: Probably not the best way of doing it unless you have another recommendation?  @mevius

Comment: For stuff that needs to cross-pollinate I use an options page.

Comment: @Aibrean an option page? What do you mean by that? Sorry for being a noob!

Comment: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/ - it's basically a page where you can define global options.

Comment: @Aibrean i've echoed out the variable that is set on the case study template using "relationship" you can see the values that are getting printed. How do i get the page title out now as part of my foreach loop? http://bit.ly/1it0jRl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out in the end. I've got the relationship to the page coming out now and now i've got the color custom field that was defined on the services template coming out on the case studies page.

So i defined the field name in a variable;

```
$cStudyRelationship = get_field("service_case_study_relationship", $cStudyId);
```

Then did the following;

```
        $cStudyRelationshipId = '';
        $caseStudyTitleColor = '#000';
        if(isset($cStudyRelationship[0])){ 

            $cStudyRelationshipId = $cStudyRelationship[0]->ID; 

            $caseStudyTitleColor = get_field("case_study_title_colour",$cStudyRelationship[0]->ID);
            $caseStudyTitleColor = '#'.ltrim(trim($caseStudyTitleColor),'#');

        } ?>
```

So built up the array for the color field created in ACF and then echoed that out against the ID  the case study was related to. Hope that makes sense! Not the best at explaining stuff as you can tell.

The last piece of the jigsaw was to apply the color value against the page relationship page title;

```
<?php echo get_the_title($cStudyId); ?> <?php echo '- '?> <span class="colouredTitle" style="color:<?php echo $caseStudyTitleColor; ?>;"><?php echo ($cStudyRelationship[0]->post_title); ?></span>
```

Thank you to those that have taken the time out to contribute to this question.